# Aquamacs for macOS Mojave and Catalina - error in process filter: ‘recenter’ing a window that does not display current-buffer. How can I fix this bug?

Tags: emacs, macos-mojave, aquamacs, macos-catalina

I'm a very new Mac user and not really an Emacs user. I just use emacs to run [PVS Specification and Verification System](http://pvs.csl.sri.com), by typing the `pvs` command in the terminal to start the software.

Aquamacs was working properly but suddenly it started to get stuck when running some `.pvs` files (not all), including some that were working normally before. I'm receiving the following message:

> "error in process filter: ‘recenter’ing a window that does not display current-buffer".

The Aquamacs windows freeze, and I just can force it to ends by using the Mac tool or closing the terminal. My Mac was running macOS Mojave when the error started, but after I updated to Catalina the bug continued.

As I'm a new Mac user a beginner in Emacs, I really appreciate any help to fix this.

Comment: It should probably be in Emacs.SX instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate for the [Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go in the menu and enable "Options => Enter Debugger on Error".  Then reproduce the problem.  Hopefully you'll get a backtrace which should give you some more info about the origin of the problem.  If it doesn't help, post that backtrace (ideally in Emacs.SX, or otherwise here).

Comment: I can't find the "Enter Debugger on Error" in the "Options" menu of Aquamacs. I'm using Aquamacs 3.5  GNU Emacs 25.3.50.1.

Comment: Then try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET`